# mobile app working with live calls

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework

Is it possible for an app to handle a live call? For instance, if I answer a call and then want an app to transfer the call, can I have the app interact and take over the call?

Comment: I don't think it's possible in android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No this is not possible on a non-jailbroken iOS device. Apple expressly forbids third party apps from doing things like this, and goes to great lengths to prevent it.

I can't speak to android. I'll leave that part of the answer to somebody else.